# нужна помощь с обходом блокировки от провайдера или РосКомНадзора с помощью http-proxy в python3

Tags: python-3.x, get, proxy, request, requests

надо использовать одновременно подмену useraget и прокси.

нашел 2 способа.

Первый [для подмены user-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226781/changing-user-agent-in-python-3-for-urrlib-request-urlopen)

```
import urllib.request
req = urllib.request.Request(
url, 
data=None, 
headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Второй для использования proxy (не помню где нашёл)

```
import urllib.request

htmlsource = urllib.request.FancyURLopener({"http":"http://127.0.0.1:8080"}).open(url).read().decode("utf-8")
```

Возможно ли с использованием urllib заменить и proxy и useragent?

Изначально я грешил на модуль **requests**, поскольку ошибка выводила меня [на данную статью](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url). Решил отказаться от модуля **requests** и использовать **urllib**, но попытка использовать **urllib** также не сработала.

Проблема заключается в том, что сайт **www.coinexchange.io** не открывается с Русского ip адреса. И отвергает любые попытки использовать прокси. пробовал много разных вариантов, ни один не сработал.

В общем надо с помощью прокси получить данные с coinexchange.io

Подойдут любые варианты

```
import requests
proxy1 = {"http": "http://PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT"} # прокси
url = "https://www.coinexchange.io/api/v1/getmarkets" # url с которого необходимо получить данные
url2 = "http://httpbin.org/ip" # дополнительный url для проверки работоспособности прокси

r = requests.get (url2, proxies=proxy1, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
r2 = r.content
r3 = loads (r2)
#  с дополнительного url данные приходят


data = requests.get (url, proxies=proxy1, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) # ошибка тут
r2 = data.content
r3 = loads (r2)
```

---

Дополню сообщение.

У меня на пк используется динамический ip-адрес.
Значит, скорее всего, проблема не связанна с тем, что мой ip находится в блэк-листе coinexchange. Но сайт не открывается без впн.
Значит, либо мой провайдер блокирует, либо ркн.

Для обхода блокировки я пытаюсь использовать только прокси (без впн).
Я уже перепробовал десятки прокси серверов, и каждый из них я предварительно проверяю:

Я отправляю только 1 запрос, но полная трассировака ошибки выглядит так:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python-Home\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Python-Home\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
File "C:\Python-Home\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
File "C:\Python-Home\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "C:/python/projectArbitr/test.py", line 138, in <module>
data = requests.get (url, proxies=proxy1, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) # ошибка тут
File "C:\Python-Home\Anaconda3\envs\projectArbitr\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python-Home\Anaconda3\envs\projectArbitr\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python-Home\Anaconda3\envs\projectArbitr\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Python-Home\Anaconda3\envs\projectArbitr\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python-Home\Anaconda3\envs\projectArbitr\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 513, in send
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.coinexchange.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/getmarkets (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000533DA90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

Поиск информации по данной ошибке выводит меня [вот сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url). Из чего я понял, что трассировка не совсем верная, ведь я отправляю только 1 запрос. Но перепробовав все предложенные варианты с данной страницы, результат я так и не получил.

Нужны любые варианты с использование прокси, поскольку весь остальной код использует именно их.

Comment: Ну вроде в случае прокси вместо `.open(url)` должен нормально работать `.open(req)` с тем объектом Request из первого примера, не?

Comment: нет, к сожалению снова падает в ошибку. я никак не могу определить проблему, сейчас добавлю фрагмент кода, похоже что проблема в чём то другом.

Comment: Ваш код с использованием requests у меня работает. Какой текст ошибки у вас?

Comment: Внёс правки в вопрос.

Comment: Во-первых, coinexchange.io не блокируется РКН. Во-вторых, он нормально открывается с русских адресов. Проверил с трёх разных провайдеров Иркутска. Вам стоит обратиться в техническую поддержку вашего провайдера.

Comment: Я просто уже не знаю куда копать, прокси менял десятки раз, 
IP у меня динамческие, бан по железу тоже не подходит т.к только что попробовал зайти с отдельного пк и не заходит.
Похоже что дело в моём провайдере. 
Единственное странно что через впн запускается, а через прокси нет.